# sort javascript object based on multiple property based on there priority

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, sorting

I have an object, i am using `ng-repeat` but need to show item in sortable formate 
sorting should be done on the total value if total value is same for multiple item than sorting should be done based of there p1 value if p1 is same than p2 and if p2 is also same then p3.i have already sorted object on based of total value but stuck in priority how to sort on based on multiple object property ?.

i have done sorting on based of value and key but needed help on this complex situation

```
   {    "QVC":{
            "p1":0,
            "p2":12,
            "p3":12,
            "total":24,
            "org":"QVC"
        },
        "TURNER & TOWNSEND":{
            "p1":12,
            "p2":12,
            "p3":0,
            "total":24,
            "org":"TURNER & TOWNSEND"
        },
        "EDF ENERGY":{
            "p1":12,
            "p2":0,
            "p3":12,
            "total":24,
            "org":"EDF ENERGY"
        },
        "TOWERS WATSON":{
            "p1":6,
            "p2":0,
            "p3":6,
            "total":12,
            "org":"TOWERS WATSON"
        },
        "VODAFONE UK LTD":{
            "p1":0,
            "p2":1,
            "p3":0,
            "total":1,
            "org":"VODAFONE UK LTD"
        },
        "DENPLAN LTD":{
            "p1":1,
            "p2":0,
            "p3":0,
            "total":1,
            "org":"DENPLAN LTD"
        }

    }
```

Comment: please leave a comment if you going to  vote-done

Comment: so you need an array with applied sort on it?

Comment: yes, the same array i m going to iterate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an array first and then sort it with [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a callback with the wanted sort hierarchy.

```js
var object = { "QVC": { "p1": 0, "p2": 12, "p3": 12, "total": 24, "org": "QVC" }, "TURNER & TOWNSEND": { "p1": 12, "p2": 12, "p3": 0, "total": 24, "org": "TURNER & TOWNSEND" }, "EDF ENERGY": { "p1": 12, "p2": 0, "p3": 12, "total": 24, "org": "EDF ENERGY" }, "TOWERS WATSON": { "p1": 6, "p2": 0, "p3": 6, "total": 12, "org": "TOWERS WATSON" }, "VODAFONE UK LTD": { "p1": 0, "p2": 1, "p3": 0, "total": 1, "org": "VODAFONE UK LTD" }, "DENPLAN LTD": { "p1": 1, "p2": 0, "p3": 0, "total": 1, "org": "DENPLAN LTD" } },
    array = Object.keys(object).map(function (k) { return object[k]; });

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.total - b.total || a.p1 - b.p1 || a.p2 - b.p2 || a.p3 - b.p3;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is exactly same what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort object but you can create array of object keys with `Object.keys()` and sort it

```js
var obj = {"QVC":{"p1":0,"p2":12,"p3":12,"total":24,"org":"QVC"},"TURNER & TOWNSEND":{"p1":12,"p2":12,"p3":0,"total":24,"org":"TURNER & TOWNSEND"},"EDF ENERGY":{"p1":12,"p2":0,"p3":12,"total":24,"org":"EDF ENERGY"},"TOWERS WATSON":{"p1":6,"p2":0,"p3":6,"total":12,"org":"TOWERS WATSON"},"VODAFONE UK LTD":{"p1":0,"p2":1,"p3":0,"total":1,"org":"VODAFONE UK LTD"},"DENPLAN LTD":{"p1":1,"p2":0,"p3":0,"total":1,"org":"DENPLAN LTD"}}

var sort = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return obj[b].total - obj[a].total || obj[b].p1 - obj[a].p1 || obj[b].p2 - obj[a].p2 || obj[b].p3 - obj[a].p3;
})

console.log(sort)
```

Then you can use that sorted array of keys to return object values in sorted order

```js
var obj = {"QVC":{"p1":0,"p2":12,"p3":12,"total":24,"org":"QVC"},"TURNER & TOWNSEND":{"p1":12,"p2":12,"p3":0,"total":24,"org":"TURNER & TOWNSEND"},"EDF ENERGY":{"p1":12,"p2":0,"p3":12,"total":24,"org":"EDF ENERGY"},"TOWERS WATSON":{"p1":6,"p2":0,"p3":6,"total":12,"org":"TOWERS WATSON"},"VODAFONE UK LTD":{"p1":0,"p2":1,"p3":0,"total":1,"org":"VODAFONE UK LTD"},"DENPLAN LTD":{"p1":1,"p2":0,"p3":0,"total":1,"org":"DENPLAN LTD"}}

var sort = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return obj[b].total - obj[a].total || obj[b].p1 - obj[a].p1 || obj[b].p2 - obj[a].p2 || obj[b].p3 - obj[a].p3;
})

sort.forEach(function(e) {console.log(obj[e]) });
```

Comment: You can try http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript